# How to make dictionary with Keras class weights per class name?

Tags: keras

How does keras and assigns 0,1,2... to my classes? Each class in my dataset, has a unique name that is a str (z,zg,zm,...) and not number.

For instance,

```
test['LITHO_CLASS_CD'].unique()=['k' 'v' 'zf' 'zg' 'zm'],
```

I calculate the weights

```
weights = sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', test['LITHO_CLASS_CD'].unique(), test['LITHO_CLASS_CD'])
```

I tried to create a new dictionary custom

```
class_weight={}
for i in range(0,len(weights)):
    class_weight.update({test['LITHO_CLASS_CD'].unique()[i] : weights[i]})
```

But this gives error

ValueError: Expected class_weight to be a dict with keys from 0 to one less than the number of classes, found

The following works, but how does keras know what is 0,1,...?

```
class_weight = dict(enumerate(weights))
```

EDIT
Keras get the input as

```
target=test['LITHO_CLASS_CD']
target_label = list(set(target_data))

encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(target)
target_label = encoder.classes_  # classes
target_encoded = encoder.transform(target)
target_encoded = to_categorical(target_encoded, num_classes=len(target_label))
 ...
blah blah 
...

history = model.fit(training_data, target_encoded,
                                  epochs=150, batch_size=32,class_weight=class_weight)
```

Comment: which labels did you pass to keras model.fit ?

Comment: Keras gets the the ['k' 'v' 'zf' 'zg' 'zm'] as labels

Answer (score 0):

First, amount of data and amount of labels should be the same. After that, if your data consists of texts, you can use `word2vec` algorithm. Otherwise you can use `MultiLabelBinarizer()` from sklearn

Comment: Edited my post. The training data is an array of floats, the labels a vector of str.